# Reload View with new model using AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problem with reloading View using AJAX call.

There is a controller called `Syzyf` and two `Index` actions (one without parameters and one with string parameter).

In `Index` view, there are checkboxes from which I create action parameter.
The action is called by button which calls function below.

The problem is that I can't get View reloaded. When I've debugged script in console I got code 200 response with new model. 
How to refresh `Index` view with script below ?

```
$('#refreshTasks').click(function () {

    var checkboxesChecked = $('#checkBoxes input:checked');

    var priorities = [];

    checkboxesChecked.each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var id = input.attr('id');
        priorities.push(id);
    });

    var filter = JSON.stringify(priorities);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Syzyf/Index",
        data: { filters: filter },
        success: function (result) {
        }
    });
});
```

And finally actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (CheckIfSyzyfConfigured(CustomMethods.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)))
        {
            using (var ctx = new SyzyfContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
                using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "GetListTaskWeb";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                    param.ParameterName = "userId";
                    param.Value = CustomMethods.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var model = Read(reader).ToList();
                        ctx.Database.Connection.Close();
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("NotConfigured");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string filters)
    {
        if (CheckIfSyzyfConfigured(CustomMethods.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)))
        {
            using (var ctx = new SyzyfContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
                using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "GetListTaskWeb";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                    param.ParameterName = "userId";
                    param.Value = CustomMethods.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                    if (filters != null)
                    {

                        var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(filters);
                        var priorsXml = test.Select(p => new XElement("prior", p));
                        var mainXml = new XElement("Priorities", priorsXml);
                        var xmlString = mainXml.ToString();

                        var param2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
                        param2.ParameterName = "statusFilter";
                        param2.Value = xmlString;
                    }

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var model = Read(reader).ToList();
                        ctx.Database.Connection.Close();
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("NotConfigured");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your view based on HTML Element.

```
var filter = JSON.stringify(priorities);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Syzyf/Index",
        data: { filters: filter },
        success: function (result) {
             $('[HTML_element]').empty().html(result);
        }
    });
```

**Note**: Return only html what you want to refresh (Not entire page/partial view) or get specific content from `result` returned by controller.

**Update**: It is always a good practice to return `PartialView` from controller in this type of scenario.